# Optimize reindexing ArrayObject

Tags: php, reindex, arrayobject

I need an optimized or custom function to update the indexes of object extends ArrayObject

Example:

```
<?php

class MyCollection extends ArrayObject
{
    // my logic for collection
}

$collection = new MyCollection([
    'first',
    'second',
    'third',
]); // will output [0 => 'first', 1 => 'second', 2 => 'third']

$collection->offsetUnset(1); // will output [0 => 'first', 2 => 'third']

// some reindex function
$collection->updateIndexes(); // will output [0 => 'first', 1 => 'third']
```

Comment: use `array_values` which would reset the keys?

Comment: @web-nomad array_values work with array, not with object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`exchangeArray`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.exchangearray.php) to swap out the inner array with one that's been run through [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). You can combine this into a method on your custom `MyCollection` class:

```
class MyCollection extends ArrayObject
{
  public function updateIndexes() {
    $this->exchangeArray(array_values($this->getArrayCopy()));
  }
}
```

See https://3v4l.org/S8I7Z